# Using Syncroniation wait/notify complete stops program from working Android

Tags: java, android, synchronization, countdowntimer, cyclicbarrier

I am trying to stop the for loop and wait until the method has finished and continue once it has called `onFinish`. I was suggested to use either `CyclicBarrier` or `syncronized wait/notify`, but neither of them work.

When I run the method without the `"stoppers"`, it always reaches to the `onFinish`, calling all 3 `System.out.prints`, but when I add either `CyclicBarrier or syncronized` it just does not start `ticking`. Meaning it only prints the first line `countDownTimer first call` and then stops and does nothing. 
Just to make it shorter I have added both `stoppers` here to show how I did either of them, but I did use them seperately.

What can I do to make it `"tick"` ?

```
    cyclicBarrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    object = new Object();


    for (int i = 0; i < sentenceList.size() - 1; i++) {
        String currentLyricLine = sentenceList.get(i).content;

        long diff = sentenceList.get(i+1).fromTime - sentenceList.get(i).fromTime;
        int interval = (int) (diff / sentenceList.get(i).wordCount);


        if(isFirstLine) {
            startLyricCountDownTimer(diff, interval, currentLyricLine, coloredLyricsTextViewFirstLine);
            isFirstLine = false;
        } else {
            startLyricCountDownTimer(diff, interval, currentLyricLine, coloredLyricsTextViewSecondLine);
            isFirstLine = true;
        }


        //First tried with this
        synchronized (object) {
            try {
                object.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Then tried with this
        try {
            cyclicBarrier.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}


private void startLyricCountDownTimer(final long millisInFuture, final int countDownInterval, String lyrics, final ColoredLyricsTextView coloredLyricsText){
    System.out.println("countDownTimer first call" );
    coloredLyricsText.setText(lyrics);

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new CountDownTimer(millisInFuture,10) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    System.out.println("countDownTimer second call + " + millisUntilFinished);
                    //Do some stuff (irrelevant since it never gets here)
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    System.out.println("countDownTimer last call" );
                     //First tried with this
                    synchronized (object) {
                        object.notify();
                    }

                    //Then tried with this
                    try {
                        cyclicBarrier.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
        }
    });


}
```

If i understand correctly then it was also mentioned that I run my loop on UI thread which is why everything stops. And well I do not wish to stop the UI thread, just to wait for one `countDownTimer` to finish, then start a new loop.